# Aligning \operatorname's with \phantom

Tags: align, math-operators, phantom

Consider the following MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
A&=\sin x +{}\\
&\phantom{{}={}}\sin y
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

If instead of `\sin x` and `\sin y` I had `x` and `y`, everything would be aligned nicely.
However, with `\sin` (or any other `\operatorname{}`), I get the following misaligned output.

[image: Output]

How would I go about correctly aligning the two lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeX adds a thin space between `\phantom{{}={}}` (which it treats as an ordinary atom) and an operator atom such as `\sin`. You fix it by adding `\!` in between.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
A&=\sin x +{}\\
&\phantom{{}={}}\!\sin y
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]